# Cloud9 and CloudFormation - access EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

I'm creating a cloud9 instance in cloudformation as follows:

```html
Resources:
  DevEnv:
    Type: 'AWS::Cloud9::EnvironmentEC2'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet
      Name: MyEnvironment
      InstanceType: !Ref Cloud9InstanceType
```

Subsequently, I want to run a bash script on that EC2 instance (within the cloudformation script) to set it up properly. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't. [`AWS::Cloud9::EnvironmentEC2`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloud9-environmentec2-repository.html) doesn't expose UserData or something like that and you cannot run SSM Documents against Cloud9 instances.

The closest you can get is using [`Repositories`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloud9-environmentec2-repository.html) to clone a AWS CodeCommit into the instance, and that repository has a script that you run manually first time you connect...